# How to avoid automatic display of new ListBox items

Tags: wpf, listbox

I do have a listbox in my WPF application. When the user has scrolled to the top and a new item arrives (it's an ObversableCollection) the new one is shown as new top one.

Can I change the behaviour in the way that when a new item arrives the scroll position is not changed meaning the new one is out of sight above the original top item.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you insert new items at the top of you ObservbleCollection so they show up on top of listbox. If you add them to the end of source, when they will show up at the end of ListBox. Or in case you have some sorting (via CollectionViewSource for example) then you need to modify you sorting logic to show added items at the end.

Comment: it's sorted by date - newest one on top (which is something which makes sense for a Twitter client). So changing the sorting is not possible in this case :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a ScrollIntoView method but it is not going to preserve the position only that it is somewhere in the list.  If the item is below it is put in the last position.  So if you put the "proper" last time into view to push the fist off as if the item is below it bring it to the last position.  I have a simple list of 3 and I made the ListView Height=40 so it only had room for 2. The following pushed the first item out of view.

lvKDNames.ScrollIntoView(liIDName[2]);

If Height=Auto is will be more difficult to determine the proper last item but this is a possible approach.

Comment: Hm - this might be indeed a way I can go. I am anyway in the collection changed event of the Oberservable Collection and I could determine if the newly added item has a newer date than the current top one - if so after display is finished I would ScrollIntoView the now second one again. This with a counter of new items and I would always know the index I need to scroll to.

Comment: This is something I will try - will give feedback if (and how exactly) I got it working as expected. Thanks :)